# wsimport not using complex input types

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, wsimport

When I use wsimport to generate proxies for some services, the resulting method signature for each port does not seem to use the complex types specified in the WSDL; but yet I've noticed that with some other services it does.

This has happened on multiple services, but the most recent example is Amazon's AWSEConsumerService ([link to WSDL](http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl)). When I generate the service proxy code using wsimport, I get method signatures such as the following for each port.

```java
@WebMethod(operationName = "ItemLookup", action = "http://soap.amazon.com/ItemLookup")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "ItemLookup", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01", className = "com.aws.CommerceService.ItemLookup")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "ItemLookupResponse", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01", className = "com.aws.CommerceService.ItemLookupResponse")
public void itemLookup(
    @WebParam(name = "MarketplaceDomain", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")
    String marketplaceDomain,
    @WebParam(name = "AWSAccessKeyId", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")
    String awsAccessKeyId,
    @WebParam(name = "AssociateTag", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")
    String associateTag,
    @WebParam(name = "Validate", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")
    String validate,
    @WebParam(name = "XMLEscaping", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")
    String xmlEscaping,
    @WebParam(name = "Shared", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")
    ItemLookupRequest shared,
    @WebParam(name = "Request", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")
    List<ItemLookupRequest> request,
    @WebParam(name = "OperationRequest", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
    Holder<OperationRequest> operationRequest,
    @WebParam(name = "Items", targetNamespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
    Holder<List<Items>> items);
```

I would expect this method take the single complex parameter specified by the WSDL (in this case an ItemLookup object). Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something or is there something abnormal happening with the code generation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem with AWS. I followed the API setup description for Java (page 10 of this [pdf](http://s3.amazonaws.com/awsdocs/Associates/2011-08-01/prod-adv-api-gsg-2011-08-01.pdf)

In step 2 (it says for Eclipse 3.2) you should create a file (sugessted name is jaxws-custom.xml) with the following content:

```
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl" xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
 <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

and then run the wsimport command with the option -b jaxws-custom.xml

I haven't figured out what exactly the problem is, but that did the trick for me.

Comment: This worked for me. Although the original code wasn't unusable, this certainly resulted in much cleaner and more readable code. I'm still curious why some services result in this but others don't.

Comment: The wsdlLocation can also be a local file.