# jax-ws generation: @WebMethod vs. @ResponseWrapper

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have two very similar wsdl-files, that generate different Java-Code. In the first case I get a method with a @WebMethod-annotation and a return value, in the second case a method with @ResponseWrapper-annotation and no return values is generated. I would like to have return values.

### 1. Service1

```
<wsdl:operation name="foo">
        <wsdl:input  name="deleteUser"         message="tns:deleteUserRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output name="deleteUserResponse"  message="tns:deleteUserResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault name="ServiceFault"        message="tns:ServiceFault"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

generates:

```
    @WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "commonReturnType", targetNamespace = "http://www.foo.com/fooSchemaTypes-v3.0/", partName = "returnValue")
public CommonReturnType foo(
    @WebParam(name = "fooType", targetNamespace = "http://www.foo.com/fooSchemaTypes-v3.0/", partName = "user")
    FooType user)
    throws ServiceFault
;
```

### 2. FooBarService

```
    <wsdl:operation name="fooBar">
        <wsdl:input name="fooBar" message="tns:fooBarRequest"></wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="ackFileResponse" message="tns:fooBarResponse"></wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="ServiceFault" message="tns:fooBarFault"></wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

genereates:

```
  @WebMethod
@RequestWrapper(localName = "fooBar", targetNamespace = "http://www.foo.com/fooBarSchemaTypes-v1.0/", className = "com.foo.fooBar.v1_0.GetFileType")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "fooBarResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.foo.com/fooBarSchemaTypes-v1.0/", className = "com.foo.fooBar.v1_0.CommonReturnType")
public void ackFile(
    @WebParam(name = "id", targetNamespace = "")
    String id,
    @WebParam(name = "timestamp", targetNamespace = "")
    XMLGregorianCalendar timestamp,
    @WebParam(name = "anotherId", targetNamespace = "")
    String anotherId,
    @WebParam(name = "fileId", targetNamespace = "")
    String fileId,
    @WebParam(name = "returnCode", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
    Holder<ReturnCode> returnCode,
    @WebParam(name = "errorMessage", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
    Holder<String> errorMessage);
```

The code that generates the code is exactly the same.

If necessary, I can provide the markup for the messages and the types. I hope anonymising didn't mess up the relevant parts.

I would like to have the second version also with a return value. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has helped (still not understanding, why this is necessary in case 2, while it was not necessary in 1):

```
<!--JAX-WD Customization: disable wrapper style rules
  see also: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/customizations.html#2.2_Wrapper_Style
-->
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="v1.0/dxpInsurerServiceV1.0.wsdl" xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
 <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

in jaxws-custom.xml

and this is in the generating ant-task:

also see:  [wsimport not using complex input types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013365/wsimport-not-using-complex-input-types)